# Windows API to Arduino Serial write works once but sends corrupted data when the same message is rewritten

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, arduino, serial-port

I am using a third party WinAPI-based Serial library (SerialPort) in a C++ program to command a LED strip (iLED and pixel color), but it turns out it only seems to work for one command - if I send the same command a second time, the color of that pixel takes another random colour and for some reason the first LED turns on too with a random colour.

Here is a link to a video of what happens when the simplified code below is run, i.e. when pixel 3, 5 and 7 are commanded over and over to be red, green, and blue respectively.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RRAshnhPz96YGJtmETy3vuGi25QjxqJz/view?usp=drivesdk

I suspected the Serial.read() weren't synchronised so I added a start byte but it didn't seem to work either, that's what the code below does.

What is happening ?

SerialPort.h (source: https://blog.manash.me/serial-communication-with-an-arduino-using-c-on-windows-d08710186498)

```
#ifndef SERIALPORT_H
#define SERIALPORT_H

#define ARDUINO_WAIT_TIME 2000
#define MAX_DATA_LENGTH 255

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

class SerialPort
{
private:
    HANDLE handler;
    bool connected;
    COMSTAT status;
    DWORD errors;
public:
    SerialPort(char const *portName, unsigned long baudrate);
    ~SerialPort();

    int readSerialPort(char *buffer, unsigned int buf_size);
    bool writeSerialPort(char *buffer, unsigned int buf_size);
    bool isConnected();
};

#endif // SERIALPORT_H
```

SerialPort.cpp (source: https://blog.manash.me/serial-communication-with-an-arduino-using-c-on-windows-d08710186498)

```
#include "serialport.h"

SerialPort::SerialPort(char const *portName, unsigned long baudrate)
{
    this->connected = false;

    this->handler = CreateFileA(static_cast<LPCSTR>(portName),
                                GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                                0,
                                NULL,
                                OPEN_EXISTING,
                                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                                NULL);
    if (this->handler == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND){
            printf("ERROR: Handle was not attached. Reason: %s not available\n", portName);
        }
    else
        {
            printf("ERROR!!!");
        }
    }
    else {
        DCB dcbSerialParameters = {0};

        if (!GetCommState(this->handler, &dcbSerialParameters)) {
            printf("failed to get current serial parameters");
        }
        else {
            dcbSerialParameters.BaudRate = baudrate;
            dcbSerialParameters.ByteSize = 8;
            dcbSerialParameters.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
            dcbSerialParameters.Parity = NOPARITY;
            dcbSerialParameters.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE;

            if (!SetCommState(handler, &dcbSerialParameters))
            {
                printf("ALERT: could not set Serial port parameters\n");
            }
            else {
                this->connected = true;
                PurgeComm(this->handler, PURGE_RXCLEAR | PURGE_TXCLEAR);
                Sleep(ARDUINO_WAIT_TIME);
            }
        }
    }
}

SerialPort::~SerialPort()
{
    if (this->connected){
        this->connected = false;
        CloseHandle(this->handler);
    }
}

int SerialPort::readSerialPort(char *buffer, unsigned int buf_size)
{
    DWORD bytesRead;
    unsigned int toRead;

    ClearCommError(this->handler, &this->errors, &this->status);

    if (this->status.cbInQue > 0){
        if (this->status.cbInQue > buf_size){
            toRead = buf_size;
        }
        else toRead = this->status.cbInQue;
    }

    if (ReadFile(this->handler, buffer, toRead, &bytesRead, NULL)) return bytesRead;

    return 0;
}

bool SerialPort::writeSerialPort(char *buffer, unsigned int buf_size)
{
    DWORD bytesSend;

    if (!WriteFile(this->handler, (void*) buffer, buf_size, &bytesSend, 0)){
        ClearCommError(this->handler, &this->errors, &this->status);
        return false;
    }
    else return true;
}

bool SerialPort::isConnected()
{
    return this->connected;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "serialport.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SerialPort serial("COM3", 115200);

    while(1) {
        unsigned char buffer[] = {255,3, 254, 0, 0};
        serial.writeSerialPort((char*)buffer, 4);
        unsigned char buffer2[] = {255,5, 0, 254, 0};
        serial.writeSerialPort((char*)buffer2, 4);
        unsigned char buffer3[] = {255,7, 0, 0, 254};
        serial.writeSerialPort((char*)buffer3, 4);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Arduino firmware

```
#include <FastLED.h>

#define BAUDRATE 115200
#define N_BYTES_MSG 4
#define N_LEDS 120
#define DATA_PIN 6

CRGB leds[N_LEDS] = {0};

void setup() {
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2811, DATA_PIN, BRG>(leds, N_LEDS); //I don't know why the colours are BRG on this strip
  FastLED.show();
  Serial.begin(BAUDRATE);
}

void loop() { 
  //Check for a quadruplet of bytes (iLED R G B) led by start byte
  if(Serial.available() >= N_BYTES_MSG+1 && Serial.read() == 255) {    
    //Read message
    unsigned char buf[N_BYTES_MSG] = {0};
    for(unsigned char i=0; i < N_BYTES_MSG; i++) {
      buf[i] = Serial.read();
    }

    if(buf[0] < N_LEDS) { //Valid ID
      leds[buf[0]] = CRGB(buf[1],buf[2],buf[3]); //Update LED state in internal representation
      FastLED.show(); //Refresh LEDs based on internal representation
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the LED strip seems to work properly on its own, since I successfully tested moving at constant speed a single pixel.
The LED strip itself is the easiest debug route I have since I didn't manage to make readSerialPort() work yet and the COM port is hogged by the program so I can't get a handle on it (can we sniff that somehow?).

Comment: It only belongs on Arduino SE if the problem comes from the Arduino code for sure... If you are certain, I would rather have an answer. In the meantime it could just as well come from the SerialPort library.

Comment: Your `main` is populating a 5-byte buffer containing your start byte, but only writing 4 bytes to serial.  This will put it out of step with your read loop on the Arduino, which is looking for the start byte _plus_ 4 additional bytes.  Or at the very least, you'll never receive the last color channel, since it was never sent.  Instead, you'll eat the next start byte and use it for that color channel, then ignore the next command.

Comment: Hi Mister, does the answer solved your issue? Feel free let me know if it is still not working for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I test serial.writeSerialPort on Windows 10 desktop with Arduino Uno. It works for me.

The following is the code I used:

On windows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "serialport.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SerialPort serial("COM4", 115200);

    while (1) {
        unsigned char buffer[] = { 255,3, 254, 0, 0 };
        serial.writeSerialPort((char*)buffer, 5);


        unsigned char buffer2[] = { 255,5, 0, 254, 0 };
        serial.writeSerialPort((char*)buffer2, 5);

        unsigned char buffer3[] = { 255,7, 0, 0, 254 };
        serial.writeSerialPort((char*)buffer3, 5);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

On Arduino:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX

#define BAUDRATE 115200
#define N_BYTES_MSG 4
#define N_LEDS 120
#define DATA_PIN 6

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(BAUDRATE);
  mySerial.begin(BAUDRATE);
  mySerial.println("Start reading.");
  delay(5000);
}

void loop() { 
  //Check for a quadruplet of bytes (iLED R G B) led by start byte
  if(Serial.available() >= N_BYTES_MSG+1 && Serial.read() == 255) {    
    //Read message
    unsigned char buf[N_BYTES_MSG] = {0};
    for(unsigned char i=0; i < N_BYTES_MSG; i++) {
      buf[i] = Serial.read();
    }

    for(unsigned char i=0; i < N_BYTES_MSG; i++) {
      mySerial.print(buf[i]);
      mySerial.print(",");
    }

      mySerial.print("\r\n");

      //Serial.write("Read complete!");
  }
}
```

I print the received data on Arduino:

[image]

**I notice that the printed data messed up when the Windows sends fast as you did in the while(1) without delay. So try adding a delay between two writes to see if it works.**

**Add also note the problem as @paddy pointed out.**

[image]

> I didn't manage to make readSerialPort() work yet

Set `unsigned int toRead = buf_size;` in SerialPort.cpp works for me. Use the following code to read:

```
    unsigned char readBuffer[20] = {};
    serial.readSerialPort((char*)readBuffer, 20);
    printf((char*)readBuffer);
    printf("\n");
```

Read from Arduino result:

[image]

Comment: You were right, adding a delay of 10ms worked for me. I still wonder why this scheme did not allow the code to work as is, since it was supposed to flush if out-of-sync and flushing is faster than sending 115kbauds. Mystery !